# Where should user configuration files go?

Tags: configuration, directory-structure, home, dot-files

If I look at my home directory there are a large number of dot files. If I am creating a new program that needs a user configuration file, is there any guidance where to put it? I could imagine creating a new dot directory `~/.myProgramName` or maybe I should add it to `/.config` or `~/.local`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `.config` directory is a newish development courtesy of [XDG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XDG) that seems, deservedly, to have won favour.

Personally, I don't mind a dot directory of your own.  A bunch of separate dot files (ala bash and various old school tools) in the toplevel of $HOME is a bit silly.  Choosing a single dot file is a bad idea, because if in the future you realize maybe there are a couple more files that would be good to have, you have a possible backward compatibility issue, etc.  So don't bother starting out that way.  Use a directory, even if you are only going to have one file in it.

A better place for that directory is still in `~/.config`, unless you are very lazy, because of course you must first check to make sure it actually exists and create it if necessary (which is fine).  Note you don't need a dot prefix if your directory is in the .config directory.

So to summarize:

- use a directory, not a standalone file
- put that directory in `$HOME/.config`